# How Does G++ Find Headers I Don't Have?

Tags: c++, header, g++, codeblocks

I'm new to C++ and trying to understand how it is finding headers.  Originally I was just trying to find out what classes are available for me to include in my source code.  I believe that different compilers will use different include directories, and hence class availability will vary.  My plan was to find the "include" directory that the compiler was using and assume I can include anything there.  So I am just getting more confused as I go.

First, I am writing C++ code in Code::Blocks, on Windows 7.  The IDE is set to use GNU GCC for compilation, which I learned means it uses the G++ compiler for C++ code.  I found my compiler here: C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-g++.exe, Code::Blocks settings point to that.

So I assumed that G++ must be using C:\MinGW\include recursively to find all its headers.  To test my theory, I searched for "iostream.h".  To my surprise, I do not even have "iostream.h" on my C drive.  Despite that, my code compiles and works when I include that.

So my questions:

1. How is G++ finding the iostream header when my hard drive does not even have it?
2. Will all the standard C++ headers (as listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct1as7hw.aspx) be available to all C++ compilers?  with the same exact name so I don't have to change my source code?

Comment: <iostream> is not the same as <iostream.h>

Comment: Joe, I thought the ".h" was only omitted in the source code, while the file on my file system would still have the file extension.  I had read similar comments before, but thought people were only talking about the source code, not the file itself.  Apparently I was wrong, the file itself actually has no extension.  Now I found it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the second question, the standard does not require the headers to be available as files. It requires the `#include` directive to be present in the program and the compiler to behave as if the declarations that the standard required were present in the program. But the compiler is free to inject the declarations in any way it deems fit.

That being said, g++ in particular does have files backing up each one of the headers. Without knowing your particular configuration I cannot tell you where the headers will be but you can stop the compilation process *after* the preprocessor and examine the output:

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::cout << "Hi\n";
}
$ g++ -E test.cpp | head -10
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream" 1 3
# 42 "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream" 3

# 43 "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream" 3
```

The paths above are on a MacOSX Lion, and it shows that in this particular configuration `iostream` is included from `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream`. In windows `head` might not be available, but you can redirect the output to a file and read it from there.

Comment: I used "g++ -E main.cpp > myoutput.txt".  The output contains a ton more data than I care about.  I like the -v option.

Comment: @msknapp: -v will provide you with the path the compiler has compiled in, but in many cases you might find that the paths can be changed by passing arguments. Copying the g++ command line and substituting the -c by -E allows you to see exactly which header was picked in this run (as compared with what header the compiler has baked in). There is a lot of information (the whole result of the preprocessor) but it is quite easy to search in your favorite text editor for the name of the include `iostream` in this case. You can also do `g++ -print-search-dirs`...

Comment: ... I use the `-E` quite often to understand what the compiler is really seeing (after macro substitution, once all includes are resolved) and determining the location of the includes is just one of the bits of information that you can obtain.

Comment: useful information, I will keep that in mind next time I am unsure which files got included.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Using quotation marks will search the current directory before moving to the ones it would search with angle brackets. There are other directories than the files listed in `\include`. That's where you'll find the ones without any extension. You may have a `c++` folder in there with those files inside, but even searching for them from within the CodeBlocks directory using the Windows 7 search shows you where they're located.
2. Yes, they should all be accessible with the same name, using angle bracket includes to reach them. Of course there is always a small chance that some might be missing. If this is the case, that implementation would seem pretty unreliable from first sight. All major compilers today should definitely adhere to this.

To use your own headers with your classes in them, they should be in the same directory as the main cpp file, and you should use quotation includes.

Comment: not within CodeBlocks directory, within C:\MinGW.  CodeBlocks itself contains no compiler (at least in my case).  Apparently my windows explorer search should have omitted the ".h".  What you said about quotes with include statements is useful to know, thanks.

Comment: @msknapp, my apologies. I always have that stuff in my CodeBlocks directory since I carry it around on my flash drive and it's all in one place there. I've had to search through that before, and I do so from within the C::B directory, so my mind immediately rushed to that conclusion.

Comment: MinGW **is** in the Codeblocks directory if you install the codeblocks version that includes MinGW. If you install them seperately the MinGW installer will prefer C:\MinGW (to avoid spaces in the name, though this has never given me any problems).

Answer (score 1):

1) The reason you can't find iostream.h is there's no such header, it's spelled `iostream` in standard C++.  If you try `#include <iostream.h>` it will fail, so it isn't finding headers you don't have :)

If you run `g++ -v test.cpp` it will show all the paths it uses to look for headers when compiling `test.cpp`

2) Yes, they wouldn't be *standard* headers if they were missing or had different names depending on your compiler!

Comment: You said "it's spelled iostream".  I heard this before, the reason I was confused is I thought they were only referring to the source code, not the file itself.  To clarify, _the_ _file_ "iostream.h" does not exist.  Regarding the second answer, you are right, I was just confused because I could not find the standard header files in g++ until now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: I've used Code::Blocks for very little time, but for what I remember in Dev-C++ and MSVC++, the headers are in the IDE's directory. (For example, my MSVC++ include directory is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include, and it HAS the iostream file.)

Answer 2: The most common header files are in the most common IDE's / compilers' set.

Tip: Did you not mean "iostream" instead of "iostream.h"?

Comment: My Code::Blocks directory apparently has no compilers at all, nor any "include" directories when searched from windows explorer.  When you run the IDE, you must configure it and point it to a compiler.  In my case, I pointed it to C:\MinGW.

Comment: Then it is in the MinGW directory. Maybe i you search for `iostream` instead of `iostream.h` you'll find the files.